# Is it possible to link and transfer Business Profile Insights data to BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-business-profile-api, google-business, google-business-profile

In Google Business Profile you are able to download a CSV of Insights data for a chosen date range. Is it possible to link and transfer this data to Big Query, similar to linking GA4 data to BigQuery?

I have tried looking for a way to link Business Profile to export data to BigQuery, but have not found anything.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no automatic link to export Google Business Profile Insights (now called "Metrics") to BigQuery, it is possible to create a process that does that via the [Business Profile Performance API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/performance/rest). Google created a reference implementation of such a process in Python [here](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/performance/rest) that you could copy.